Making Visually Lossless GIFs and Animated WEBPs
Which software can make the best visually lossless gifs out of videos? Also, how do I use rgb and/or rgba when making visually lossless animated WEBP files?

Please do some research, and try asking a more specific question. For checking the Animated WebP options using FFmpeg, execute ffmpeg -h encoder=libwebp_anim. Making visually lossless GIF is not possible in most cases, because animated GIF uses a palette of 256 colors, and doesn't support "24-bit true color".
